# Call to a member function find() on a non-object in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

I am getting error of

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

when I am adding following code.Although rest are working except sale_channel , when I try to do same as others then getting this error.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $zones = $this->{$this->modelClass}->Zone->find("list", [
            'conditions' => ['is_active' => 1],
            'order' => ['name' => 'ASC']
        ]);
        $states = $this->{$this->modelClass}->State->find("list", [
            'conditions' => ['is_active' => 1],
            'order' => ['name' => 'ASC']
        ]);
        $cities = $this->{$this->modelClass}->City->find("list", [
            'conditions' => ['is_active' => 1],
            'order' => ['name' => 'ASC']
        ]);
        $sale_channel = $this->{$this->modelClass}->SaleChannel->find("list", [
            'conditions' => ['is_active' => 1],
            'order' => ['name' => 'ASC']
        ]);
        //$sale_channel = $this->SaleChannel->find("list", array('conditions' => array('is_active' => 1)));
        $this->set(compact('zones', 'states', 'cities', 'sale_channel'));
    }
```

Model Code is

```
class SaleChannel extends AppModel {

/**
 * Associations
 */
var $hasMany = array(
    'Outlets' => array(
        'className' => 'Outlet',
        'foreignKey' => 'outlet_id',
        'type' => 'INNER'
    )
);
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'), 'message' => 'This field is required.',
        ),
    )
    );

}
```

Comment: is the main modelClass having proper relation with the SaleChannel in the model?

Comment: please write the model relations as well as the above code is incomplete and going by the above code, it seems fine but may be error in some relations or loading the Model.

Comment: @RohitAilani if i use loadModel instead of modelClass.. then it is working but sale_channel has further relation with other , so I cant use LoadModel. this one is only way left , but gives me error

Comment: @RohitAilani please check edited code

Comment: you have not any relation with SaleChannel, plz confirm

Comment: what about the relations in the Outlet Model as you are using the Outlet Controller I guess. You need to create a relation in that model as well as per your query. Or else you can load the SaleChannel directly and can run the find as is there in your commented code.

Comment: thanks , I got it.. you gave me hint for that.. my problem has been solved.